# DHCP server with static IP not resolving hostnames (clients do)

Tags: linux, networking, dns, gentoo, dhcp

## Network Setup

- I have a server which I am trying to set up LXCs on
- I am using LXD which forces me to use DHCP
- DHCP is working fine already
- due to my setup I need to be able to access the containers using their hostnames

  - this works now using the `.local` TLD

## Problem

The problem now is that I need to access the containers using their hostnames from the host too which does not receive it's configuration from the DHCP server. Currently this does not work.

### Edit

This does work when I set the DNS server of the host interface to it's own ip. I still cannot ping the host from anywhere.

### Workaround

I could just put the host with it's ip in the host's */etc/hosts* file, but I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.

## Host Setup

The host is running Gentoo GNU/Linux 4.1.5 (OpenRC).

*/etc/conf.d/net* looks as follows:

```
dns_servers="8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"

config_eth0="<static IP>"
routes_eth0="default via <static gateway>"
fallback_eth0="dhcp"


rc_net_lxcbr0_provide="!net"

config_lxcbr0="10.2.0.1/24"
brctl_lxcbr0="setfd 0
sethello 10
stp off"
bridge_lxcbr0=""

dns_domain_lxcbr0="local"
dns_servers_lxcbr0="10.2.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"
```

*dnsmasq* is configured like this (comments removed):

```
local=/local/
interface=lxcbr0
listen-address=10.2.0.1
expand-hosts
domain=local,10.2.0.0/24
dhcp-range=10.2.0.2,10.2.0.128,255.255.255.0,12h
dhcp-range=<static ip range>, 12h
enable-ra
```

## Container Setup

The containers just run their DHCP client.

## Hostnames

Let's just assume those:

- host
- cont1
- cont2

## Pings

The upper row shows who is pinged.
The left column shows who is pinging.

Pings are run in the form `ping <machine>.local` e.g.: `ping host.local`.

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       | host  | cont1 | cont2 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| host  |  no   |  yes  |  yes  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| cont1 |  no   |  yes  |  yes  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| cont2 |  no   |  yes  |  yes  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to just add 10.2.0.1 as a DNS server on the host and to add the following lines to */etc/dnsmasq.conf*:

```
address=/host.local/10.2.0.1
address=/host.local/<ipv6 address>
```